# return all columns when filtering matrix with Numpy pythonically

Tags: python, numpy

I have tried several methods and cannot get both columns back. The filtering works, but only returns one column.

```
import numpy as np
<<<<read in some data, now get counts>>>>
unique, counts = np.unique(data[0::,2], return_counts=True)
x = np.asmatrix((unique, counts))
x = x.astype(np.int).T
print x
```

now I get the following

```
[[100001      1]
 [100002      1]
 [100003      4]]
```

I want to filter on the second column > 3

```
y = x[x[:,1] > 3,].T
print y
```

I now have only the first column

```
[[100003]]
```

why am I not getting?

```
[[100003     4]]
```

Comment: When I run your code I get the result that you want.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider using `asarray` instead of `asmatrix` :

```
x = np.asarray((unique, counts))
```

Then it should work as you except.

When I run your code on python 3.4 / numpy 1.10.1, if i use `asmatrix` I get:

```
>>> x = np.asmatrix((unique, counts))
>>> x = x.astype(np.int).T
>>> y = x[x[:,1] > 10,].T
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/matrixlib/defmatrix.py:318: 
VisibleDeprecationWarning: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 1;
dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
  out = N.ndarray.__getitem__(self, index)
```

Comment: Old `numpy` does this 2d boolean indexing without warning.  To select rows of `matrix` `x`, the index needs to be a 1d array, e.g. `(x[:,1]>10).A1`.  This is another case where `np.matrix` has some hidden pitfalls.

Comment: first upgraded to 1.10.4. then switched to array. then changed a few lines. `x = np.asarray((unique, counts)).T`, then `x = x.astype(np.int)` then `print x[x[0::,1]>3]` and it worked!